# reducing memory usage of program

Tags: c++, memory, numbers, int

I am trying to solve a problem that has a memory usage limit of 0.75 mb
I can't make arrays of size 100 000 since it is not within 0.75 mb

My program is the following:

```
#include <iostream>   
#include <String>
using namespace std;

void main() {
char temp;
int temp1, num, k, z, val__=0;
cin >> num;
int* value = new int[94000];
short* place = new short[94000];
for (int i = 0; i< num; i++) {
    cin >> temp>>temp;
    if (temp == 'U') {
        cin >> temp >> temp >> place[val__] >> value[val__++];
    }
    else {
        cin >> temp >> temp1;
        for (k = val__-1; k >=0; k-- ) {
            if (place[k]==temp1) {
                cout << value[k]<<endl;
                for (z = k; z < val__; z++) {
                    value[z]=value[z+1];
                    place[z]=place[z+1];
                }
                val__--;
                k = 0;
            }
        }
    }

}
}
```

How do I calculate memory usage globally for C++ programs, and how can I reduce the amount of memory used?
In one array I store numbers from 0 to 1000; in the second I store numbers from 0 to 10^9

Comment: `val__` is a reserved identifier.

Comment: Do you need to reduce your memory usage, or figure out how to increase your stack size?

Comment: i need a program that does the same but uses less memory :) to be able to create arrays of size 100 000

Comment: If the system has enough, a dynamic array of 100000 is easily possible like that.

Comment: there is limit in testing system :(

Comment: Maybe describe in words and comments what your program does then it should be easier to see how to improve on it. Also this question may be better suited at [codereview.se].

Comment: main() should return an int not void

Comment: Post the format of the input file along with the **specific** nature of the problem you're code is failing to solve. *"It has to be under 750kB"* is ***not*** the problem you're trying to solve. *"I have to read 1000 numbers, sort them, square them, and write them to stdout in sorted order, using no more than 750kB of memory."* or some similar description is what we me by "State the problem you're trying to solve."

Answer (score 1):

You have two arrays, assume sizeof(int) is 4 bytes, and sizeof(short) is 2 bytes
then you use just 600000 bytes plus a little bit for heap management.
I think, that other memory takes stack or other types of memory.
Probably you have to reduce stack?

Comment: yes. in this case what is the most stack consuming part of this programm and how to reduce its size

Comment: Setting stack size platform and tools specific. I don't think you need too big stack, using debuger you can estimate resonable stack size.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to solve exactly.
but, if you need more memory than what you can allocate,
(and assuming you don't want to increase allocated memory size )
than you might want to save your data in a database or in a file,
reading only the parts of the array you need for processing and 
freeing them from memory before loading more items into the program running memory.